# For each functional $f$ there exist an $x$ such that some properties hold

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm trying to prove or disprove the following statement:

> Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed $\mathbb{R}$-vector space.
>
> 1. For each $f\in X^*$ there exists $x\in X$ with $\|x\|\leq 1$ such that $f(x)=\|f\|$

Now intuitively I would say this is true since the operatornorm is defined as
$$\|f\|=\sup\limits_{\|x\|\leq 1}|f(x)|$$
So we could choose $$f(x):=\sup\limits_{\|x\|\leq 1}|f(x)|$$

But I'm not sure if the following still holds: $$\sup\limits_{\|x\|\leq 1}|f(x)|=\left\|\sup\limits_{\|x\|\leq 1}|f(x)|\right\|$$

What also keeps me doubting my solution is the fact that I did not use the Hahn-Banach theorem. I had to prove another statement that was very similar but about the existance of a linear functional for each $x\in X$ with $f(x)=\|f\|$, where I used the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we choose $x$ so that $f(x)=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}|f(x)|$, we're assuming the result.  That is, we're assuming that there exists $x\in X$ with $\|x\|\leq 1$ so that $f(x)=\|f\|$.

Otherwise, I'll point out that the result is true when $X$ is finite-dimensional.  In finite-dimensional normed vector spaces the closed unit ball $\{x\in X:\|x\|\leq 1\}$ is compact, meaning that $f$ achieves a maximum value on this ball, and this maximum value must be $\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} |f(x)|$.  The result can fail, however, when $X$ is infinite-dimensional (because the closed unit ball is no longer necessarily compact).  For examples of this failure, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199472/linear-continuous-function-on-a-norm-space).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't quite understand the example in the other question particularly I don't understand one notation: $a=\langle a_n :n\in \mathbb{N}\rangle \in l^\infty$
Does this mean every span $\langle a_n \rangle \in l^\infty$ or that $a$ as a whole is in $l^\infty$?

Comment: The notation $a=\langle a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\rangle\in\ell^\infty$ says that $a$ is a sequence in $\ell^\infty$ (the space of bounded sequences), and that the $n$-th term in this sequence is $a_n$.  The accepted answer on that question chooses particular values for $a_n$ and defines a map from $\ell^1$ to itself using these values.

Answer (score 1):

As Austin has pointed out, the statement is not necessarily true in the infinite-dimensional case.

I would like to add that (in the Banach space case) there actually exists a precise characterization of when your statement is true: it is true if and only if $X$ is reflexive.

This is the content of [James' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%27_theorem).

*Edit:* I'm of course talking about Banach spaces here. I initially overlooked that you are concerned with general normed spaces. Thanks to Aweygan for pointing this out.

Comment: That would be the case for Banach spaces, but there are (necessarily nonreflexive) normed spaces for which all bounded linear functionals attain their norm on the closed unit ball.  See [this](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02771466)

Comment: Yes, thank you! @Aweygan